# How to get a client created for a web service that requires SAML token

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl, ws-federation

Alright so I've been tasked with essentially automating some web service requests that go out within my company. Since I know the wsdl location, I created a simple blank console application and added a service reference pointing to that wsdl. VS created the proxy class and the app.config file that goes along with it just fine. Here is the app.config file that it generates:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <customBinding>
            <binding name="TestBinding">          
              <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12">
              </security>
              <httpTransport/>
            </binding>
              <binding name="STSBinding">
                <security allowInsecureTransport="False"
                  authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
                  requireSignatureConfirmation="false"
                  messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12">
                </security>          
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10" />
                <httpsTransport/>
              </binding>           
          </customBinding> 
          <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>            
                <binding name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_TestsService">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <message establishSecurityContext="false" issuedKeyType="BearerKey"
                            issuedTokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0">
                            <issuer address="https://sts.abc.com/idp/sts.wst" bindingConfiguration="STSBinding" binding="customBinding"/>
                            <issuerMetadata address="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/ws-trust-1.3.wsdl" />
                            <tokenRequestParameters>
                                <trust:SecondaryParameters xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
                                    <trust:TokenType xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0</trust:TokenType>
                                    <trust:KeyType xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
                                    <trust:Claims Dialect="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity"
                                        xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
                                        <wsid:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"
                                            Optional="true" xmlns:wsid="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity" />
                                        <wsid:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"
                                            Optional="true" xmlns:wsid="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity" />
                                        <wsid:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/AppId"
                                            xmlns:wsid="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity" />
                                        <wsid:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Environment"
                                            xmlns:wsid="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity" />
                                        <wsid:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/SecondLvlAuthzId"
                                            xmlns:wsid="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity" />
                                    </trust:Claims>
                                    <trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#</trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm>
                                    <trust:EncryptionAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc</trust:EncryptionAlgorithm>
                                </trust:SecondaryParameters>
                            </tokenRequestParameters>
                        </message>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://Tests.abc.com/201308/TestsService.svc"
                binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_TestsService"
                contract="ServiceReference1.TestsService" name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_TestsService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I've added the CustomBindings myself obviously trying to play around with it. So far I've got pretty much error after error as I'm trying to use the client like this:

```
TestServiceClient vClient = new TestServiceClient();
ServiceProcessingDirectivesType vType = new ServiceProcessingDirectivesType();
UserContextType vUserContextType = new UserContextType();
ServiceCallContextType vServiceCallContextType = new ServiceCallContextType();
GetSummaryRequest vRequest = new GetSummaryRequest();

vClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Test";
vClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Pass";

vClient.GetSummary(vType, vUserContextType, ref vServiceCallContextType, vRequest);
```

I have virtually no control over the web services that are out there. I'm not sure of the best way to continue debugging the issues. Am I missing stuff from configuration still? If I am, how should I know that?

The latest error I am stuck on right now is:
"{"Unable to determine partner SP connection by AppliesTo: https://dc-balances-acp.fmr.com/201308/BalancesService.svc"}"

Answer (score 0):

You are using Federated Security.

What the error is saying is that it cannot find the Service Provider to use.

The Client address in Your config and the service that is Called according to the error do not match.

It appears that Your program is not using the config that you posted.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've confirmed that the application is correctly using the app.config file settings. Is there potentially something wrong with my configuration?